# Using Windows 10 in a virtual machine. Can it be done?

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine, sandbox

I am currently running 8.1. I'd like to try out Windows 10 and if I like it upgrade. If not, I'll keep running as I am.

I've never used a virtual machine before: can Window 10 be used from a virtual machine as a "sandbox", and if so how?

Comment: The only problem you will face is getting your hands on a .ISO after July 29th.  The worst case you wait until they restart the Insider Preview program and install that.  Windows 10 will install without a license key, and its being reported, there won't be restrictions your installation just won't be activated..

Comment: Fortunately is before July 29! :-) Where do I get the .ISO? (I do have a Windows 10 invitation. Is that worth feces?)

Comment: Microsoft pulled the Insider Preview .ISO last week.  You won't be able to activate new Windows 10 machines until July 29th.  There won't be a way to activate previous builds of the insider Preview, only builds released after July 29th, can be activated.  You can install Windows 8.1 within a virtual machine, upgrade that installation on July 29th, that is the best solution.  Microsoft distributes free trial Windows 8.1 virtual machines compatible with Hyper-V, VirtualBox, and VMWare

Comment: Thank you.  And now I get to do the thing I hate the most: wait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already "tagged" your question with a perfectly suitable answer... read up on how to use [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/)... it'll do exactly what you want...

You can get a 90-day evaluation of Windows 10 Enterprise [from Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-windows-10-enterprise).